# TextBlock Binding?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I add code in .cs

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty lbStatusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("lbStatus", typeof(string), typeof(SingleTalkView),
        new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string lbStatus
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(lbStatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(lbStatusProperty, value); }
    }
```

in xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding lbStatus}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Height="24"/>
```

And then add a global value

```
private string a = "Test";
```

and in init function

```
this.lbStatus = a;
```

Finally I add a button and change a's value,the TextBlock doesn't change!why?
Thx~~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String, in .NET, is an immutable type.  When you type:

```
this.lbStatus = a;
```

You set lbStatus to a reference to the string currently pointed to by the `a` variable.  Later, when you change a:

```
a = "Foo";
```

You're not going to change `this.lbStatus`, since you're assigning the `a` variable to a completely new string instance.

Comment: @Yagami Typically, you'd bind to a Property of a class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  You can refer to my article on WPF's data binding, which is very similar to the binding in Windows Phone: http://reedcopsey.com/2009/11/25/better-user-and-developer-experiences-from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm-part-4-data-binding/

Answer (score 0):

This might help you understand better

```
public class Base : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {      
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }       
    }

//ViewModel
public class ViewModel : Base
private string _value;
        public string value {
            get
            {
                return _value;
            }
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("value");
            }
        }
//View
<Textbox Height="60" Width="60" Foreground="Wheat"
                         Text="{Binding value,Mode=TwoWay}" >
```